# contour integral of $\exp(iz)/z$

Tags: integration

I want to calculate the following integral: $\int_\gamma \frac{e^{iz}}{z} dz$ on the contour $\gamma:[0,\pi] \ni \theta \mapsto \epsilon e^{i\theta}$. I'm only interested in the complex part (real part is irrelevant for me).
When I use the standard method for calculating these integrals that gives me: $$\int_0^\pi ie^{i\epsilon e^{i\theta}} d\theta$$ Which doesn't get me any further.

Comment: Where did this problem come from?

Comment: Is this a part of calculating contour integral?

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested in the limit for $\epsilon\rightarrow 0^+$, you can use Jordan's trick, that says:

let $\gamma_{\epsilon}=z_0+\epsilon e^{i\theta}$, $\theta\in[\alpha,\beta]$, with $f$ having a simple pole at $z_0$, then
$$\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0^+}\int_{\gamma_{\epsilon}}f(z)dz=(\beta-\alpha)\cdot i\cdot\operatorname{Res}(f,z_0)$$
In your case,
$$\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0^+}\int_{\gamma_{\epsilon}}\frac{e^{iz}}{z}dz=(\pi-0)\cdot i\cdot\operatorname{Res}\Big(\frac{e^{iz}}{z},0\Big)=\pi\cdot i\frac{e^{iz_0}}{1}=\pi\cdot i$$